# Would a Netgate 1100 with pfSense Plus Software support SquidGuard?

Tags: hardware, http-proxy, pfsense, squidguard

Would a [Netgate 1100 with pfSense Plus Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MTMPXKG) support SquidGuard?

I'd like to be able to do web filtering using that software / hardware combination.

P.S. Apologies if I have posted this in an incorrect StackExchange, if so please move the question to the appropriate StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this would be a good idea as the Netgate 1100 is not performant enough for such operations, it has just not enough processing power, your services would lag or even crash. Make yourself a favor and buy a `Supermicro A2SDI-2C-HLN4F` mainboad with an onboard server Atom CPU with `ECC`/`registered-ECC`-memory support for round about 250€. Get 8GB RAM and a Western Digital Blue Series SSD (SATA) (WD Blue series have a longer lifetime compared to other equal priced SSD) and a case of your choice. Cost for all round about 400€ with round about 20W power usage. This mainboard is supported by pfsense and you get a real and powerfull hardware firewall for 20% of its original price and you can use all of pfsense modules and features without to worry.

Comment: pfsense uses freebsd, this mainboard was just a good tip for a very stable, cheap, small and power efficient board - prices for a hardware firewall are up to 2000€ for an equivalent model

Comment: I think the fact that you're visiting paladin's older questions with a biased view based on your interaction with him from a different question is disgusting @Kusalananda. How can you be a moderator?! This privilege should be taken away from you.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for your support. I've edited my answer to make clear why it would not be a good idea to use a Netgate 1100, like leeand00 asked.

Comment: @Daniel It is common to look at a user's other answers if one of them is flagged as having some kind of issue. If you feel strongly about this, then please consider bringing it to our Meta site for discussion.

Comment: @paladin Thank you for improving your answer.  It reads much better now.